# Facebook Page Stats - accessible via Opengraph?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the analytics from a Facebook page through an API. I'd like to use it to monitor page stats alongside Google Analytics (which uses GAPI) as we run various campaigns.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep: see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/ for the details, but you can basically read all the insights as documented at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#Metrics.

You'll need to grant your application the *read_insights* permission for the page, but once you've done that you should be able to reach in and get the data you want.